# Unable to add Laravel package Intervention Image - Requirement could not be met

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5, intervention

I am trying to install [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation) into my Laravel 5 app.  Below is my `require` from my `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "laravel/cashier": "~3.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "~2.0",
        "illuminate/html": "5.0.*@dev",
        "intervention/image": "~2.2@dev"
    }
```

Upon running `composer update` I get an error saying: `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.`

The full output from Composer can be found below.  I'd like to point out that Composer is on the latest version (with `composer self-update`).

```
mikemike@workspace:~/workspace/workspace (master) $ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.3
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.1
    - way/generators 2.0 requires illuminate/support 4.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
    - way/generators 2.1 requires illuminate/support 4.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
    - way/generators 2.2 requires illuminate/support 4.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
    - way/generators 2.3 requires illuminate/support ~4.1 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - way/generators 2.4 requires illuminate/support ~4.1 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - way/generators 2.5 requires illuminate/support ~4.1 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - way/generators 2.6 requires illuminate/support ~4.1 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - way/generators 2.6.1 requires illuminate/support ~4.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.14|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.18|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.29|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.0.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.10, v5.0.11, v5.0.12, v5.0.13, v5.0.14, v5.0.15, v5.0.16, v5.0.17, v5.0.18, v5.0.19, v5.0.2, v5.0.20, v5.0.21, v5.0.22, v5.0.23, v5.0.24, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.27, v5.0.28, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.0.9].
    - Installation request for way/generators ~2.0 -> satisfiable by way/generators[2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.6.1].

mikemike@workspace:~/workspace/workspace (master) $
```

I have tried a few different values inside the `require` line, including `dev-master` and I have tried installing via a single composer line, which both give the same error (`php composer.phar require intervention/image`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem:

```
- Installation request for way/generators ~2.0 -> satisfiable by way/generators[2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.6.1].
- way/generators 2.6.1 requires illuminate/support ~4.0
```

As `illuminate/support` is a package included in `laravel/framework`, their versions have to match. In your case, you have `5.0.*` for `laravel/framework` and `~4.0` (`4.*`) of `illuminate/support` is required. These don't match and the dependencies can not be installed.

This means you have to use Laravel 4 or find another package. (or another version of `way/generators` that supports laravel 5).

Comment: Perfect.  `way/generators` just adds some generators into artisan, which I no longer need anyway, so I'll just do away with it.  Thanks.